# Rich client object management

Tags: java, swing, jpa, rcp, entitymanager

I have been troubled by this for quite some time now and hope someone could shed some light on me.

On a rich client platform like Swing/RCP, etc, how can I manage the entity objects that are retrieved from the database?

If I don't use Client/Server architecture, but let the Client connect directly to the database, with the help of JPA/EntityManager this works quite well. In this case all the entity objects on the UI are managed by the EntityManager, all the relationship among them are also well maintained, no problem with LazyInitialization Exception from JPA as well, cause both the Client and the EntityManager is in the same JVM. There will be no duplication of objects with the same entity.

However, If I want to separate the server from the client, and the Client UI only deal with the DTO objects which are mapped from the Entity, it gives me a big headache to make those DTO object in sync. With every server request new DTOs object are created, even though they are representing the same server side entity. The client side DTO's relationship is also very fragile. Change in one object is not easy to be seen from all the duplications of the same entity.

IS there any framework that can act as a client side EntityManager, or a cache mechanism that could work in this scenario? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Wudong

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink supports a RemoteSession architecture that gives the EclipseLink Session and UnitOfWork interface to a remote client communicating back to the server-side session.

This was something popular back before JavaEE and webservices back in the fat client three-tier architecture days.  It has not been used much since, and does not currently support JPA.  Nowadays most people have web-clients instead of fat clients, or seem to prefer to control their own client/server communication through DTO's or use XML, so I'm not sure a remote EntityManager is the best architecture.

You could log an enhancement on EclipseLink for this functionality, as it would not be hard to extend the existing RemoteSession, or you could use the native EclipseLink API.